# Neo4j bean classes are not loaded in docker deployment version

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have a problem with  SessionFactory bean package scanning … my application is using spring boot and spring data neo4j … If I run the app via spring boot , everything works fine and all of my bean classes get loaded in the session factory without any problem. The problem shows up when  I use the docker deployment version… for some reasons the packages are not loaded properly in “org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.DomainInfo”  class … So the classNameToClassInfo map remains empty after initialization.  In other words “return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "XXX.XXX.XXX.beans");” does not  work for docker deployment version.

has anyone ever had a similar issue ?
any idea?

Comment: please open an issue at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues

Comment: Thanks @Luanne  , I will.

Comment: This is the issue [link](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/211)

Comment: produces `Neo4jSession is not an instance of a persistable class` - for SEO, guys
cause it was very hard to find a damn answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Luanne mentioned , I filed an issue in github  for this. However I found a workaround to solve this.The problem is that the current version of neo4j OGM does not support ".war" file scanning in the ClassPathScanner class ... & unfortunately I am putting a war file into my container. So instead of putting a ".war" in the docker container , I put a ".jar" version of my spring boot app in the container and it worked ! So if deploying a war in the container is not mandatory , you can try this solution , otherwise you have to wait till the issue [link](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/211) is resolved. :-)